# Error auto resize length of array in C

Tags: c, windows, process

I have a program to execute some process and show ID of them:

Main function:

```
int main(void){
char code[25];
bool testCmd = false;
DWORD arrProcessID[10];
char *fullCmd;
char *parameter;
char *command;
char *extraCmd;
int loop = 1;
while (loop == 1){
    printf("C:\\>");
    scanf("%[^\n]",code);
    fullCmd = strdup(code);
    command = strtok(fullCmd, " ");
    extraCmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
    parameter = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if ((strcmp(command, "list") == 0) || (strcmp(command, "LIST") == 0)){
        if (extraCmd != 0){
            printf("%s is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. \n", code);
        } else {
            printf("ID process is running: \n");
            printf("%d \n",sizeof(arrProcessID));
            for(int i=0; i<sizeof(arrProcessID); i++){
                printf("%d : %lu \n", i, arrProcessID[i]);
            } 
        }
    }

    if ((strcmp(command, "install") == 0) || (strcmp(command, "INSTALL") == 0)){
        if (extraCmd == 0){
            printf("%s is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. \n", code);
        } else {
            if  ((strcmp(parameter, "-b") == 0) || (strcmp(parameter, "-B") == 0)){
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = createBackgroundProcess(extraCmd, parameter);
                arrProcessID[0] = pi.dwProcessId;
                printf("%d \n",sizeof(arrProcessID));
                printf("%lu \n",arrProcessID[0]);
            }
        }
    }

if(strcmp(command,"exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit") == 0){
        loop = 0;
        printf("Program Terminated\n");
    }
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
return 0;
}
```

and this my function to create a process:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION createBackgroundProcess(char *exeFileName, char *parameter){
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
CreateProcess(exeFileName,NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
CREATE_NO_WINDOW,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
return pi;
}
```

But when I create only 1 processs, my array arrProcessID always have size = 40 (always = sizeof(arrProcessID) * 4) while I added 1 value in arrProcessID[0]. So, What happend with my array ?

Comment: You declare `arrProcessID` to be an array of `10` DWORDs so it will always have the same size regardless of the data you store in the array.

Comment: Keep in mind that `strdup` creates a string *that you are responsible for freeing*. You must use `free(fullCmd);` when you are done with `fullCmd` otherwise your program will leak memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DWORD arrProcessID[10];
```

See : sizeof(arrProcessID) = 40 ,Right? (`sizeof(DWORD) = 4`See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx))So your print 40 lines.

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(arrProcessID); i++){
                printf("%d : %lu \n", i, arrProcessID[i]);
            }
```

Use `i <sizeof(arrProcessID)/sizeof(arrProcessId[0])` instead of `i< sizeof(arrProcessID)` in your loop.

And if you only what to print 1 line (in case you only have one process).You can do those step:

1. use `memset(arrProcessID,0,sizeof(arrProcessID));`  to initialize the array .(all NULL now).
2. use `i <sizeof(arrProcessID)/sizeof(arrProcessId[0]) && arrProcessID[0]!= NULL` instead of `i< sizeof(arrProcessID)` in your loop.

Comment: but i don't understand why sizeof(arrProcessID) = 40 ?

Comment: @Thangnv the sizeof give you the how many bytes the array hold. One DWORD is 4 byte and you have 10 DWORD! You can see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx

Comment: Sorry I understanded about size of my array, but, can you explain for me why all item in my array have value while i until add value in arrProcessID[0], I think default is NULL, but not, DWORD always have a value, right?

Comment: @Thangnv `DWORD arrProcessID[10];` means We have the memory now.But we never know what stored in it until we initialize it or give it a value. It default is unknown. just use `memset`

Answer (score 1):

"sizeof(arrProcessID)" is total memory size of array DWORD arrProcessID[10].

If you want to know number of array's item, use "sizeof(arrProcessID) / sizeof(arrProcessID[0])".

Answer (score 1):

From the [`C99 draft standard`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator`:

> When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array

In this case you declare:

```
DWORD arrProcessID[10];
```

which is an array of `10` `DWORD`s each of which are `4` bytes in size so we have:

```
4*10 = 40
```

This is regardless of the data that is actually stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't reallocate memory to the array for the new process to use. use `realloc()` allocate memory before creating the process.